# Java - How to show price for 2 selected cities when user chooses starting city and arrival city?

Tags: java

I am writing a code for my homework project in Java. My assignment is to create bus relations and price application where user choose starting city and arriving city. Based on his selection, application must show the price. Can you help me what should I use to write this code because my teacher doesn't want to. I am using JDeveloper 11.

Comment: What did you try so far? Any effort?

Comment: Can you share your code with problem you have

Comment: I made class City with names and then class Routes which returns City and has starting point and arriving point. Then I made an arraylist for cities and combobox and it shows user choice. Now I'm stuck how to make prices for when city1-city2 is choosen, or city3-city2 and so on.

Code is on Croatian so I don't know if could help

Comment: Are you using one combo box that shows the selection as "Starting Point - Destination" or are you using two combo boxes, 1)Starting Point 2)Destination?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what are your further specifications.
You can think about it as a 2-Dimensional array where the X and Y axis are cities and their related intersection is the price.

```
New York            0         10          100
Washington         10          0           90
San Francisco     100         90            0
                New York   Washington   San Francisco
```

So you need a data structure where you can store two cities and the price to travel between them.

Not sure if you also need to implement a table for this but its, but the idea is straightforward.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately we didn't learn this. I was told to do that with an arraylist and combo box. Details are in comment if you are interested.

Comment: A `City` has a `Route`. `Route` e.g. contains a`Map` of  `City`, `Price`. If you query for city1 you see all possible routes from there then if you pick city2 - you have your price.